# Flutter long list giving NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

**I am building an app in which I have used a long list in TabBarView. But when it initiates this list it gives the following error;**

NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.

Receiver: null

Tried calling: length

See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

**Below is my main.dart;**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(
    contacts : List<String>.generate(10000, (i) {return "Contact $i";}),
));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> contacts;

  const MyApp({Key key, this.contacts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Contacts'),
              bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.smartphone)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.face))
              ]),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: contacts.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Contact ${contacts[index]}')
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Center(child: Text('hello text')),
            ]
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tested your code and it didn't throw any errors.

Comment: @loki tested the code, so why don't you start the app again. That might solve the problem